# I am getting a reference/NaN error when trying out this prompt program

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a very simple javascript program from TheOdinProject and my code keeps returning errors, specifically:

ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at eval:13:9
    at eval
    at new Promise

```
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number?');

if (number == 42) {
  let response = ("Yay! That's my favorite too!');
}
else if (number < 42) {
  let response = 'Eh, that's OK but x would be even better.';
}
else {
  let response = 'LAME. That number is too large!';
}

let x = ++response;

console.log(response)
```

I can't imagine what I'm doing wrong. At first, I was getting NaN errors so I made the 42 a string by using quotes ("42") but that didn't work either. I also tried changing the first line to: let number = Number(prompt('what is your favorite number?')); thinking that maybe the number wasn't converting to a number.

Please let me know if I need to give more information.

Comment: as there's no `eval` and no `Promise` in the code you posted. I highly doubt the error message is `response is not defined at eval:13:9 at eval at new Promise`

Comment: what do you expect `let x = ++response;` to do when response can only ever be a string - though, in the code you posted, it wouldn't even be that, because you use `let` in every `if/else` block - may I suggest some basic javascript tutorials are in order

Comment: The double quote at the start of the `Yay!` string has no matching one to close the string.

Comment: Why you are trying to increment the string value? And the double quote is not properly closed inside the If statement

Answer (score 0):

`let` is block scoped, so the `response` variable only exists inside each of your `if / else if / else` blocks. You might try declaring it outside those blocks like so:

```
let number = prompt('what is your favorite number?');
let response; // Declare here.

if (number == 42) {
  // Take care not to redeclare it here. Notice the lack of `let`.
  response = "Yay! That's my favorite too!";
}
else if (number < 42) {
  response = "Eh, that's OK but x would be even better.";
}
else {
  response = 'LAME. That number is too large!';
}

let x = ++response;

console.log(response)
```

I also noticed that some of your quotes were mismatched. Not sure if your original code was that way but make sure to avoid using single quotes if the string includes a single quote itself (to avoid terminating the string early).

Also, you should also be aware that `++response` isn't going to work, since `response` is a string, not a number.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. You're right about the single quotes, that's my mistake - they were double but I edited them to post here.

Comment: Whoops, hit enter too early. I guess what I don't understand is, what do I declare as the original 'let' variable? The variable is going to change anyway depending on the answer.

Comment: Oh god, it was just that ++response;. I meant to type ++number. Thank you so much for helping me figure that out, I was pulling my hair out. Will mark as answer.

Comment: Aha! Glad to help.